# How to access Ubuntu One server side logs for my account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, log

I would like to have info (time, filename, and user when having shared folders) about file changes, uploads, downloads...

Comment: Please vote my answer up since you have accepted it as the best which means that my answer was helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syncdaemon.log (in ~/.cache/ubuntuone/log) provides that info too. If you want to have access to server side logs, you should contact U1 team at https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/